# how can i make GUI that used to be in the old dos games but without the old look in openGL

Tags: opengl, gui

I want to build simple OpenGL application that mustily are GUI based to collect from user 
input and to the user can push buttons . 
now i saw allot of GUI frameworks that offer GUI to openGL . but none of then offer 
GUI that is seams to be part of the 3d/2d game the closed example i can think of is the old 
dos games GUI .

Comment: Your question seems vague. Do you have a screenshot of an example GUI you want to have ?

Answer (score 2):

Just about any existing UI framework that allows you to control the textures used in the GUI widgets should work -- just because none of them *ship* with an out-of-the-box "DOS" look doesn't mean they can't support one.

After all, what you are talking about is mostly just appearance. You just need to use highly pixelated (or "lo fi") textures for your UI artwork. Kind of like [this sprite set](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=8970.0), which has some bitmap letters that might be a good start for you, at least.